# gzip js on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, mod-deflate

the following configuration in httpd.conf only gzip css and html, not javascript, any idea?

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/javascript text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's most likely because the MIME type for Javascript [is hotly contested](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/02/javascript-mime-type).

Try adding `application/javascript` and `text/x-js` (as well as `application/x-javascript`)

That said, a more reliable way may be to filter based on the `.js` file extension. See the `Request_URI` directive for more info (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) - this may not work if you're using rewritten URLs that do not use the `.js` extension for JavaScript files.

If this doesn't work, then your distro of Linux may be using a completely different MIME type for JavaScript. Locate the `TypesConfig` directive in your config file, and have a look to see how it's defining JavaScript. Then add that MIME type in as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your best approach:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.[0678] no-gzip
      BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s(7|8)  !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
      Header set Vary *
      DeflateCompressionLevel 1
```

Internet Explorer (certain versions) does not play well with hectic compression, so it's best to approach compression on a browser by browser basis. These settings are from a high volume website with lots of clients - and were the only settings we tried that worked 100% of the time.